# Unable to receive XML response with the help of angular 8 HttpClient

Tags: angular

The server is sending me an XML response but I am unable to get it using HttpClient angular 8. In Postman, it is working fine.

Tried to make the responseType 'blob'. Tried to use HttpOptions. Tried to use header Allow-Encoding gzip etc.

```
let url = "My server URL";
let body = "My xml content in string";
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept', 'text/xml')
      .set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
      .set('userid', 'xxxx')
      .set('password', 'xxxx')
      .set('authkey', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

this.httpClient.post(url, body, {headers: headers, responseType: 'text'})
.subscribe(resonse => {
      console.log(resonse);
    }, err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
```

Expected: XML response
Actual: empty string("")

[image: Dev-tool output from browser]

Comment: try sending it it as plain text and then parse it to xml

Comment: Maybe the URL is not complete identical? 
Could you please share the dev-tool output from the browser?

Comment: @brandt.codes `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://xxxxxx.org/API/xmlapi2.aspx with MIME type text/plain. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

Comment: it is a CORS (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) problem. Your Code is correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of Chrome and not because of Angular. Chrome has decided that the response can't be trusted and has been replaced by null. You can try using Firefox and it should be fine. Ask your backend to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' Headers to the response which might solve the issue but it hasn't always worked out for me.

Check https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`responseType`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType) could be:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'
```

> The expected response type of the server.
>
> This is used to parse the response appropriately before returning it
>   to the requestee.

Then if you want to construct a CRUD request that interprets the body as a text string and returns the response as a string value, you can check this documentation - [HttpClient Overload #3](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get).

The response will be:

> `Observable<string>`: An Observable of the response, with the response
>   body of type string.

Then just parse to xml after sending the request as you wanted.